# How to write a conditional sql query?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called student like:

```
name age roll_no



X    Y
```

I want to write a sql query such that if name='X' and age='Y' then insert 'Z' to roll_no.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not insert rather update.

```
update table_name set roll_no = 'Z' where name='X' and age='Y'
```